# Throw Exceptions from Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want stop users to download huge reports from Jasper. REPORT_MAX_COUNT does this job but users don't know that its generated partial data.

I would like to throw an exception from Jasper when REPORT_COUNT is greater than REPORT_MAX_COUNT. So users can refine search filters accordingly. Is it possible to throw an exception from Jasper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid throwing exceptions from the report, since you can handle it otherwise.

Instead I would use these options:

1. I want to control after generating report if to display it or not (seems like your case), check if the `REPORT_COUNT >= REPORT_MAX_COUNT` after report has been filled.

Example java code:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("yourReport.jrxml");
JRBaseFiller filler = JRFiller.createFiller(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(),report); //we need the filler to get the variable value
JasperPrint print = filler.fill(map, connection);
Object rc = filler.getVariableValue("REPORT_COUNT");
Object maxRc = filler.getParameterValue("REPORT_MAX_COUNT");
if (rc instanceof Number && maxRc instanceof Number){
    if (((Number)rc).intValue()>=((Number)maxRc).intValue()){
        System.out.println("REPORT_MAX_COUNT HIT!!, doing something else...");
    }
}
```

Instead of `System.out` do your stuff, if you like `throw new Exception("OOPS")`;

2. Display a warning text inside the report if `REPORT_COUNT >= REPORT_MAX_COUNT`

Example jrxml code:

```
<summary>
    <band height="20">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#FF0033" uuid="82b89600-1787-4a86-809e-adc5babdd6b6">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()>=$P{REPORT_MAX_COUNT}.intValue()]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["REPORT_MAX_COUNT HIT"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

3. Do both.., display a warning in interface, but let the user be able to download the generated report with warning text if he likes to....

Comment: Thanks !!! We want this fix would go for many reports. Is it possible to do second option for all the reports instead of doing in every report, can we do it in Java code or some place at run time (may be scriptlet) ??

Comment: Using scriptlet you will need to change every report (include scriplet in report). If you are for example are only exporting to pdf I think the quickest way would be to include for example a watermark using itext after export... Another way could be to add element via java code directly to the JasperPrint